# How to renew time in a programme in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a maze game and it has a time limit. Like for the 1st maze the user has only 30 seconds and i used a variable time_elapsed which calculates the difference between the ending time and the starting time.

I used `starting_time=clock()` and `ending_time=clock()`. `time_elapsed = (double)(ending_time - starting_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC?` , to calculate the elapsed time, and then I used that in the equation `time_left_for_maze_one=30-time_elapsed`.

But when the user completes the first maze and goes onto the second, the time is supposed to be 50s but it starts at like 20s or 23s.This happens because the second maze's time is calculated using a similar equation: `time_left_for_maze_two=50-time_elapsed`, but over here `time_elapsed` is the one from the previous equation.

Is there a way to renew the time whenever the user completes each maze?

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2011/03/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-11-sleep-your-way-to-success/

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear from your question, but I assume you're initializing starting_time once at the beginning of the maze and updating ending_time each frame ? If that's the case you need to reset starting_time at the beginning of the new maze which in turn will reset time_elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

The [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) function computes the *processor* time (in µs generally).

You want the real elapsed time. Use [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html). On Linux, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and consider using [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_REALTIME` (or maybe `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`).

Generally, time measurement is often operating system specific (even if `time` & `clock`  are in C99). If you have a [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) implementation (e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall` with a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9), read about [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)

BTW, for programming games, you might be interested in [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/).

Comment: or use [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) instead of C or posix functions. Which would also help in calculating to the appropriate units

Comment: Only in C++11 not in previous C++ standards.

Comment: There's Boost.Chrono which works in C++03. Also `<chrono>` has been around in GCC for a long time. I believe since 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just assign a new value to `starting_time` . Since you haven't declared it as `const`, you may assign new values to it.

Possibly a cleaner solution is to have a `time_left` variable, which is initially 50 seconds. After each maze, you deduct the `time_taken` for that maze. If for a given maze, `time_taken > time_left`, you lose.

And as Basil noted, `clock()` measures the CPU time. You want just `time()`, which is known as "wall (clock) time".